# Unpassable Where Clauses LINQ-to-SQL

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql

As I'm struggling to learn LINQ I’ve managed to generate a SQL statement with "AND (0 = 1)" as part of the where clause.  I'm just wondering if this result is common in poorly written queries and is a known issues to try and avoid or if I am doing something totally backwards to end up with this.

---

Update

```
public static IEnumerable<ticket> GetTickets(stDataContext db,string subgroup, bool? active)
    {
        var results = from p in db.tickets
               where 
                   ( active == null || p.active == active ) 
                   /*(active == null ? true :
                   ((bool)active ? p.active : !p.active))*/ &&
                   p.sub_unit == db.sub_units.Where(c=>subgroup.Contains(c.sub_unit_name))
               select p;
        return results;
    }
```

If I ignore the active part and just run

```
public static IEnumerable<ticket> GetTickets1(stDataContext db,string subgroup, bool? active)
    {
        return db.tickets.Where(c => c.sub_unit.sub_unit_name == subgroup);
    }
```

It returns the groups of tickets I want ignoring the active part.

Comment: What does the LINQ query look like?

Comment: My wild guess is that he's got something which evaluates to `Stuff.Where(false)`. But yes, it would be good to see the LINQ.

Comment: Could it be doing this figure out which columns would come back if the query were to be run?

Comment: I'v boiled down the LINQ to just the statement causing the 1=0..
var results = from p in db.tickets
 where
 p.sub_unit == db.sub_units.Where(c=>subgroup.Contains(c.sub_unit_name))
select p;

Tickets have a FK to sub_units, and I have a sub_unit name (subgroup), that I want to search for. (There are multiple sub_units with different ID's but the same name, that I am trying to pull back tickets for.

Comment: I’ve been playing with this more and that lead me to realize i may need to post the full LINQ statement, since it could be simplified down far enough to work without solving my problem. (I'm adding the code above)

Comment: @Tim: Also, why is one implementation doing `.Contains()` and the other just doing `==`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd pull the processing out of the ternary operators.

```
where ( active == null || p.active == active )
```

**EDIT**

The rest of the where clause looks funky too...  why is it not just doing

```
&& p.sub_unit.sub_unit_name == subgroup
```

or

```
&& subgroup.Contains(p.sub_unit.sub_unit_name)
```

?

Answer (score 2):

That is some pretty heavy abuse of the ternary operator.

This expression:

```
(active == null ? true :
    ((bool)active ? p.active : !p.active))
```

Is equivalent to the following logic:

```
bool result;
if (active == null)
{
    result = true;
}
else
{
    if ((bool)active)
    {
        result = p.active;
    }
    else
    {
        result = !p.active;
    }
}
result &= ...
```

Think carefully about what this is doing:

- If `active` is `null`, you're fine, it skips to the next condition.
- If `active` is `true`, `result` is `true` at the end of the conditional.
- If `active` is `false`, `result` is `false` at the end of the conditional.

In the last case, the query can never return any rows!

@Tanzelax has already supplied a simple rewrite.  The main idea is that you want to compare `p.active` to `active`, not actually evaluate the condition as `p.active`.

Comment: Yeah this is open source code, so I didn't write that line, or clearly look at it close enough.  I've been chuckling since Tanzelax posted that.  I'll update the above code to reflect the change.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably caused by a null value in one you the columns you have declared as non-nullable.  LINQ2SQL makes all columns non-nullable by default.  Go back to the designer and change the fields to allow values to be null.  Unfortunately this *feature* is **By Design** (see connect.microsoft.com link below.)

[(linq) incorrect sql generated for row.column == localVar when localVar is null (should be "is null" check)](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/520096/linq-incorrect-sql-generated-for-row-column-localvar-when-localvar-is-null-should-be-is-null-check?wa=wsignin1.0)